# Testing Image upload with Django and Webtest

Tags: django, tdd, webtest, django-webtest

Does anyone know how I can test the image upload with using WebTest. My current code is:

```
form['avatar'] =('avatar', os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH, 'static', 'img', 'avatar.png'))
res = form.submit()
```

In the response I get the following error "Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you should pass file's object.

Comment: No, if file object is passed webtest returns "ValueError: File content must be <type 'str'> not <type 'file'>"

Comment: What happens if you pass image_file.read() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Power was right. Unfortunately(or not) I found his answer after I spend half an hour debugging the webtest. Here is a bit more information.

Trying to pass only the path to the files brings you the following exception:

> webtest/app.py", line 1028, in _get_file_info
>
> ValueError: upload_files need to be a list of tuples of (fieldname,
> filename, filecontent) or (fieldname, filename); you gave: ...

The problem is that is doesn't told you that it automatically will append the field name to the tuple send and making 3 item tuple into 4 item one. The final solutions was:

```
avatar = ('avatar',
           file(os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH, '....', 'avatar.png')).read())
```

Too bad that there is not decent example but I hope this will help anyone else too )

Comment: You mean `open(....)` and not `file(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays selected answer didn't help me.

But I found the way to provide expected files in the .submit() method args

```
form.submit(upload_files=[('avatar', '/../file_path.png')])
```

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3:

```
form["avatar"] = ("avatar.png", open(os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH, '....', 'avatar.png', "rb").read())
```